# Logic and Checking Tables within SQL Server Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm getting my feet wet with Stored Procedures finally and need a little assistance with my first one.

I get the basic layout and have set up a SP that does nothing but set up two variables and select them, returning no information.

Right the history, I have two main record tables `tblRecordsCurrent (RecordID)` and `tblRecordsHistorical (RecordID)` as well as a parent table to both `tblDataSet (DatasetID)` that has a flag `dsCurrent`.

Each day I upload 5000 records to tblRecordsCurrent, using a new DataSetID.  When I upload a new dataset, the previous day's dataset (5000 records) is moved to tblRecordsHistorical and the DSCurrent flag in the tblDataSet table is updated to False.

I will feed the StoredProcedure a DataSetID to move, and the destination ('C' or 'H' for Current/Historical).  First I need to check that the DataSetID exists, then if there are any records in the relevant tblRecordsCurrent/Historical with the DataSetID.

1 - How do I find out if the DataSetID exists, which I presume would be a `SELECT COUNT(*) from tblDataSet where DataSetID=@DataSet`, but how is that implemented, do I just do:

```
@DataSetExistCount=SELECT COUNT(*) from tblDataSet where DataSetID=@DataSet
if @DataSetExistCount== then
     @errCount = @errCount + 1
else
   >>> MORE LOGIC <<<
END
```

EDIT:

This was a great kick-start to my Stored Procedure, which I have now posted under a separate Error Trapping based question if anyone is interested in complex nested logic in Stored Procedures:

[Error Handling in SQL Server Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403221/error-handling-in-sql-server-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just check to see if it exists:

```
If Exists ( select 1 from tblDataSet where DataSetID = @dataSet )
begin
   -- Do your move logic
end
else 
begin
    -- Doesn't exist so do something else
end
```

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I've got some info from other sources and will post my final code to demonstrate to any would be readers, what is possible.  I won't accept the answer till then.